# Imprimir un array de fechas

Tags: php, array, date

```
Array 
(  
  [Monday] => Array
  (
    [0] => 2017-07-03
    [1] => 2017-07-17
    [2] => 2017-07-31
  )

  [Friday] => Array
  (
    [0] => 2017-06-30
    [1] => 2017-07-14
    [2] => 2017-07-28
  )
)
```

Mi objetivo es obtener una lista de fechas así:

```
        2017-07-03
        2017-07-17
        2017-07-31
        2017-06-30
        2017-07-14
        2017-07-28
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puedes iterar el array :

```
foreach (Array as $key=> $values) {
    foreach ($values as $value) {
        echo $value."<br>";
    }
}
```

de esta manera puedes imprimir el valor del sub-nivel 2 del array.

**Update: Mapeo recursivo de Array (Funciona dinamicamente independiente de los niveles)**

```
<?php
$arr = [
    'Monday' => ['2017-07-03', '2017-07-17', '2017-07-31'],
    'Friday' => ['2017-06-30', '2017-07-14', '2017-07-28']
];

function Array_Walk_Re($data)
{
    array_walk($data, function (&$value, $key) {
        echo (is_array($value) ? Array_Walk_Re($value) : $value.'<br>');
    });
}

Array_Walk_Re($arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Una solución típica es con foreach, asumiendo que el array sea `$dias`:

```
foreach($dias as $dia) {

    foreach ($dia as $fecha) {

        echo $fecha . '<br>';

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra posibilidad sería usar la función [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php):

```
$arrayDays = [

    'Monday' => [ '2017-07-03', '2017-07-17', '2017-07-31' ],
    'Friday' => [ '2017-06-30', '2017-07-14', '2017-07-28' ]
];

foreach( $arrayDays as $date ) {

    echo implode( PHP_EOL, $date ).PHP_EOL;
}
```

[Ver Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2f1ec758e5d47eb5da3785531324d274153b5823)