# ¿Cómo ejecutar el decode JSON MIXED?

Tags: php, json

Quiero crear una tabla de esa forma:

```
IdPessoaDevedor;Qtde;Idacordo;Idparcela
248754;3;1635963;3489812
248754;3;1635963;3489813
248754;3;1635963;3489814
```

¿Como hago para acceder a cada item del `array($json)`?

Mi cadena es :

```
$json = '{"IdPessoaDevedor":248754,"Qtde":3,"Itens":[{"IdAcordo":1635963,"IdParcela":3489812},{"IdAcordo":1635963,"IdParcela":3489813},{"IdAcordo":1635963,"IdParcela":3489814}]}'
```

1 - Mi programa:

```
<?php
$json = '{"IdPessoaDevedor":248754,"Qtde":3,"Itens":[{"IdAcordo":1635963,"IdParcela":3489812},{"IdAcordo":1635963,"IdParcela":3489813},{"IdAcordo":1635963,"IdParcela":3489814}]}';

$obj = json_decode($json);

foreach($obj as $key => $value) {
  echo $key . " => " . $value . "<br>";
}
?>
```

2 - El resultado:

> ```
> IdPessoaDevedor => 248754
> Qtde => 3
>
> Notice: Array to string conversion in >C:\xampp\htdocs\facil\exxx\exxx_decode_json.php on line 7
> Itens => Array
> ```

O sea, no ha leido la TAG "Itens".

La cantidad de items puede cambiar. Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Que problema tienes? Solo necesitas un `json_decode($obj_json);`...

Comment: Yo he cambiado la questión para que se quede mas aclarada. És un ejemplo, la cadena tien aun fecha de pago etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Explicación:

Esta linea: `echo $key . " => " . $value . "<br>";`

Seria correcta en un array de una sola dimensión.
Error se debe a que en algún momento le estas haciendo `echo` a `$value` y es una variable de tipo `array`.
Te recomiendo que uses recursividad; recientemente actualice esta respuesta en otro post que te debe ayudar: [Link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/83367/46896)

## La solución:

```php
$json = '{"IdPessoaDevedor":248754,"Qtde":3,"Itens":[{"IdAcordo":1635963,"IdParcela":3489812},{"IdAcordo":1635963,"IdParcela":3489813},{"IdAcordo":1635963,"IdParcela":3489814}]}';

$obj = json_decode($json);

function Array_Walk_Re($data)
{
    array_walk($data, function (&$value, $key) {
        echo (is_object($value) || is_array($value) ? Array_Walk_Re($value) : $key.'=>'.$value.'<br>');
    });
}

Array_Walk_Re($obj);
```

## Ouput:

```
IdPessoaDevedor=>248754
Qtde=>3
IdAcordo=>1635963
IdParcela=>3489812
IdAcordo=>1635963
IdParcela=>3489813
IdAcordo=>1635963
IdParcela=>3489814
```

Comment: Francisco Núñez, Muito obrigado pela ajuda, estou muito satisfeito com o resultado. Francisco, muchas gracias por la ayuda, estoy muito contento con el resultado.